# How to fix the Invoice module's total amount?

Tags: commerce

I recently started using the [Invoice](https://www.drupal.org/project/invoice) module. Everything seemed to work until the moment I was going to make some test invoices.

The total amount is wrong (see figure): 306.81 + 64.43 = 371.24, but on the invoice 371.25. Anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

[image]

It does show well in the back-end: The sum from there looks simple? 371.25 - 306.81 = 64.44, this is the only correct result (see figure).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a mistake. That moduo do rounding. See the photo:

Subtotal: 134.50
VAT: 25.55
Total: 160.06

So, the real value of VAT is 134.50*0.19=25.555 and real total is 160.055 but for invoices you need to do rounding at two decimal places. And you get total 160.06.

[image]

Comment: You can't send an invoice to a customer with a difference in the subtotal + vat and the total amount in my opinion. Is there a way to fix it? In your example: 134.50 + 25.55 = 160.05, it's rounded to two decimals. Right? Your total amount shows 160.06?

134.50 * 0.19 = 25.555 > should be 25.56 instead of 25.55, right?

Comment: Yes there is a way to fix that, you need to hack moduo and change a way for rounding.  This moduo rounding only total, he don't rounding VAT. So one way to fix is to rounding VAT, and total is only simple addition(subtotal + vat). In Serbia this is OK and in accordance with the law.